# toggle next two sibblings and hide all others

Tags: jquery

I have a number of DIVS layed out as below:

```
    <div class="click">
    <div class ="title">
    <div class ="content">
    <div class="click">
    <div class ="title">
    <div class ="content">
    <div class="click">
    <div class ="title">
    <div class ="content">
    <div class="click">
    <div class ="title">
    <div class ="content">
    <div class="click">
    <div class ="title">
    <div class ="content">
```

What I want to do is have it so when you click a content DIV, the two siblings below (click and content) will toggle so they are shown on the page and all other title and content DIVS will be hidden. I've tried this:

```
$(".click").click(function () {

         $(this).next().next().toggle();

    });
```

This shows the content DIV below whichever click DIV has been clicked. How can I modify this so it hides the others, as when you click another DIV the other ones remain open. Also how can I select both the title and content siblings? I thought .next().next() would select both but it only gets the second sibling of the active DIV.

Answer (score 2):

use hide first to hide all the elements

```
 $(".click").click(function () {
    $('.title').hide();
    $('.content').hide();
    $(this).next().toggle();
    $(this).next().next().toggle();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all content and title elements using `$('.content,.title')` selector. hide elements after using not selector along with object of content element that needs to be toggled to filter it out of collection:

```
$(".click").click(function () {
  var toggleelements = $(this).next().next().add($(this).next());
  $('.content,.title').not(toggleelements).hide();
  toggleelements.toggle(); 
});
```

**### Working Demo**

Comment: Thanks, this works but it only shows content. How can I show both content and title?

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Would you mind explaining what each line is doing?

Comment: toggleelements get the object of content and title that needs to be toggle. then you hide the other content and title elements in next line. and then toggle the content and title that needs to be toggled.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how I'd modify this so the 'click' DIV changes background colour to show it is active? Then changes back when you click a different one?

Comment: @podusmonens: like this https://jsfiddle.net/ey89Ltet/ . don't forget to accept the helped answer :)